# How do I get the colors on Windows 10 to look the same as my mac?

Tags: windows, color-profiles

I just noticed how awful my apple cinema monitor looks on windows, there's way to much contrast and it just doesn't look right. How do I get to look the same as when I display it on a mac. I tried using the icc, from my mac for apple cinema displays but I can barely notice a difference. Maybe I didn't install it correctly.

Comment: `Maybe I didn't install it correctly.` - How can we possibly know if this is the case? Why don't you reinstall it and see if it fixes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it properly is with a colorimeter.
The profiles provided with a display are far too generic to be relied on, & don't compensate for any manual adjustments made by the user, e.g. brightness/contrast etc.

The colorimeter software will calibrate to a known reference then apply it at OS-level to the screen output.
Set it independently from both OSes that use the screen, then both will be properly colour managed.

Entry-level devices from about $£€ 50 [if you're looking at the used market, avoid the Huey Pro, it no longer works on Mac, only Windows.]

Popular devices on the market are the [Spyder series from datacolor](http://www.datacolor.com/photography-design/product-overview/#workflow_2) or the [ColorMunki](http://xritephoto.com/colormunki-solutions) & [i1Display](http://xritephoto.com/i1-solutions) from X-Rite.

Personally I use the i1DisplayPro, but there are as many opinions as people when it comes to which is 'best'.