# How to fix different color scheme of monitor in windows 11?

Tags: windows, display, windows-11, colors

I have created a website and I notice something wrong. In my website I set the background color to #98A8F8 which is like violet on normal display. But in my laptop it is blue.

The weird thing is when I screenshot my website from my computer and send it to someone else. The color of the picture is violet too.

Is my computer not accepting violet color?

Here is my [website](https://gerome-tahud.netlify.app).
Here's a swatch
*[tested independently by editor]*

[image]

And here is the color from my computer:
[image: Link to image]

Comment: This appears to work for me.   Start, Settings, Personalization, Colors. Violet is acceptable.

Comment: What's the laptop model? And also what color profile do you see set in Color Management?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1224343/how-do-i-get-the-colors-on-windows-10-to-look-the-same-as-my-mac [doesn't matter what the hardware is, the solution is the same, calibration & profiling]

Comment: @Tetsujin, while calibration is indeed the best way to have it "perfect", his issue is much worse that simply not being calibrated, and any normal laptop out of the box should be able to do better than this. Which is way some software/settings solution is what he needs

Comment: @YisroelTech - I'm assuming the sunrise effect is caused by taking the photo from too high &  probably looks a lot better if you simply tip it back a bit more which will increase the contrast [I have an old Macbook Pro like that], but if you notice that whilst the 'purple' is extremely green-heavy, the greys in the scrollbar aren't too far out - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLTuw.jpg - if anything, blue-light. That could point to an interpretation issue in the browser. [contd…]

Comment: […contd] It would be interesting to know whether the swatch I edited into the question look OK to the OP [&  test multiple browsers], as I made sure it has an embedded sRGB profile.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for the edit. I will try John's suggestion but I think its already set. Also I have tried the color calibration it didn't change a thing. My laptop is HP ryzen 5 if that would help. Thank you

Comment: Is the swatch I added also affected in the same way as the actual site? Test in different browsers to see if there's variation.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. its Blue on the laptop but violet in my phone.

Comment: You need to test multiple browsers *on the same device* & also try dragging the swatch out to your computer & opening in something that can display photos. We're trying to establish whether it's caused by your display profile [or even a hardware fail] or whether it's specific to certain apps.

Comment: I used braved and Edge still the same. Even downloaded the swatch and still blue. I have opened the swatch in paint, snipping tool office, etc and I still get the same color

Comment: Try this - https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/calibrate-your-screen-windows-11 for a 'by eye' method.

Comment: What color profile do you see set in Color Management (search "Color Management" in the start menu or in the control panel)

Comment: @YisroelTech its still in default. sRGB IEC61966-2.1 and WCS thingy. I tried recalibrating but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly "didn't work"? We need details. It also surprised me that the default should be a colour standard & not a display type or manufacturer/model. I can't test here because I only have Windows in VM, so it doesn't properly connect to the 'real' hardware, but the Macs here are all calibrated to the display type.  [contd…]

Comment: […contd] Here's a picture of the settings for *both* screens, artificially placed one aboe the other. The first show the current profile [the top one is the one from the manufacturer, the next re re-calibrations & their dates] the second shows that though sRGB is amongst the options, it is not the one the display uses, it is only used for colour conversion - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXlcd.png If I check the 'this display' box, all the ones below the line vanish, as they are not valid for this display.

Comment: @Tetsujin by "didn't work" I mean it still does not show the color as intended even though I recalibrated the display

Comment: This is like pulling teeth. Take it to a repair shop & see if hands-on they can tell whether it's badly calibrated or a hardware fail.